# Dialog flow having trouble matching parameters

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am having an issue where dialogflow does a really bad job of matching paramters.

[image: Here is an image of my paramter definitions]

At first I was trying to use specific fields types like `@sys.geo-city-us` and `@sys.given-name`, but when I entered a name like Jones it matched it as a city even though I was answering the question about my name.

In the above example I answered the name question and it matched it to the company even though name and company are `@sys.any` entities.  I don't understand why in response to a question for a specific parameter with the entity type of any it fails to match and tries to plug it into another parameter value.

Is there something I am missing about how parameters are matched?

Answer (score 0):

I think this weirdness may be related to doing both `@sys.any` and setting is list.  I ended up doing `@sys.any` without is list set for the name and then parsing out the names in the code.  Then I left city as `@sys.geo-city-us`.  This seems to work for my specific case but I would caution others that multiple `@sys.any` fields can cause some weirdness, especially with is list set.

I wish there was a setting that when I ask for X whatever the user relies is taken in as X, because that is not what `@sys.any` is doing.